# Regex only contain binary number and not more than 8 digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I expect true return value that match condition below :

- Only binary number (0 or 1)
- Length not more than 8

I'm new to regex, i have googling and read JS RegExp from https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_regexp.asp but still i don't get it.

I've tried

```
/[0-1]$/
```

but still didn't match the condition above

I expect boolean return from regex test if there is contain no other number except 0 or 1 and length not more than 8.

```
data: {
  binRegExp: /[0-1]$/,
  isBinary: false,
  binNum: '', // get value from user input
},
computed: {
  inputCheck(){
    return this.isBinary = this.binRegExp.test(this.binNum)
  }
}
```

code above is vue js

Comment: Try `[01]{1,8}`

Comment: That's definitely part of any regular expressions tutorial out there... -> https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will takes 1 to 8 [1-0]

```js
const regex = /^[0-1]{1,8}$/


const text = "1010010"

console.log(regex.test(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/^[01]{1,8}$/
```

```js
let strings = ['11110001','1111000111','11112001'];

strings.forEach(x=> /^[01]{1,8}$/.test(x) ? console.log(x,'pass') : console.log(x,'not pass'))
```